# Offset box, the proper wayto do that

Tags: css, layout

After searching, testing and exhausting all Y way to do it... i cannot figure it out. How will you make the white box under the whole layout ?, it should contain the menu, the title and the content, but let those "go out" without breaking anything

sorry, i'am lost !.... please help

here is the reference file : http://studioteknik.ca/stackoverflow_question/offset.jpg

Comment: Are you asking how to make the colored boxes extend outside the white box? You can do that with negative margins. Please post some code.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1174-Negative-CSS-Margins-Are-Not-Cool.htm

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `margin` to some negative value.